# EMR Spark job - usage of HDFS and EBS storage

Tags: amazon-emr

Does Spark on EMR  distributes input data from Amazon S3 to underlying HDFS ?

What is the usage of EBS volumes which are also attached to nodes  ?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you specify HDFS or not it is always spun by the EMR. I couldn't find any documentation why EMR spins HDFS; but to my experience EMR first writes to HDFS as temporary storage and then copies these data to S3. Some part of the root volume is used to host this HDFS -- even though you didn't check HDFS checkbox when spinning EMR.

Answer (score 0):

The root EBS volume for each node is used for the operating system and application files. This is a 10GB volume by default. Additional volumes attached to the core nodes are used for HDFS. Task nodes may have additional volumes, but Task nodes do not have HDFS Name Nodes, and will not store HDFS data.

[Instance Storage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-storage.html) documentation for EMR:

> Instance store and/or EBS volume storage is used for HDFS data, as well as buffers, caches, scratch data, and other temporary content that some applications may "spill" to the local file system.

Spark will store temporary data in HDFS if configured to do that.
You can [configure properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#configuring-logging) like `spark.local.dir` to set where Spark should write data.

Unless you are specifically writing data to HDFS, you don't need to provision large EBS volumes for core nodes. I suggest launching a cluster with what you estimate you'll need, and then adding additional core nodes as your HDFS requirements increase.